# Location Based Android Development

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Development. Once we get the user's current latitude and longitude, I want to show him the list of places which are marked in Google maps. For example if my latitude and longitude are 23.00 and 72.50 respectively, then I want to show all the marked places within 10km of its radius.

Comment: use `locationchangedlistener` whenever the location will be changed you can get it on the listener.

Comment: Thanku Devendra Singh,Please give some idea in interfacing My Maps in android application or is there any other way to retreive the names of major areas/places around the current location?

Comment: if you want to get major places around you or near you, use the Google places API.[Here is a tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/)

Comment: super thanku..Do u have any idea about interfacing "My Maps" in Android application?I need to use the places marked exclusively by me.Jst as like that of above tutorial u posted.\

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the user's location you can use it to call the Google places API.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests)is a link to the documentation for it. There are a number of steps you need to take before you can just call the API. They are detailed in the start guide for the places [API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro#Introduction).

I hope this helps.

Comment: In Google places Api,I have successfully Added the places using the url https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?key=My API KEY and it returns the unique place_id as response.But When I go for nearby search with the url :https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=MYLATITUDE,MYLONGITUDE&radius=50000&type=shoe_store&key=MY API KEY .The reponse shows only the google places which has the SCOPE:"GOOGLE".What should i do to get the places added by me ie.,SCOPE:"APP"?